# How can i use the displace modifier for the whole mesh and not only part of it?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to use a displace modifier for a room (its form is rectangular). But somehow only its sides are affected and not also the up and down. How can i affect this modifier to these parts, too?

Comment: On the displace modifier there is an option for **Direction** you can change on what axis the displacement will occur.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but is there a possibility to maintain the original shape of the displacement on the sides? For the original one i've used the z direction. It's very important for me because i've created a bump map. Therefore it would fatal if the displacement would change.